I want to change the color of my graphics made with streamlit
Good morning, I need help to change the color of some graphics. We are using streamlit to graph it for an inventory replenishment interface where there are two indicators in the dataframe, one for existence and the other for sales.

# Configurar los gráficos de existencias utilizando AreaChartColumn y BarChartColumn
column_config = {
    "Existencias Totales": st.column_config.BarChartColumn(
        "EXISTENCIA",
        help="El comportamiento del inventario en los últimos meses",
        width="medium"
    ),
    "Ventas Mensuales": st.column_config.AreaChartColumn(
        "VENTAS",
        help="Las ventas mensuales en los últimos meses",
        width="medium"
    ),
    "Cantidad a reponer sugerida": st.column_config.NumberColumn("Cantidad a reponer sugerida"),
    "Cantidad a reponer confirmada": st.column_config.NumberColumn("Cantidad a reponer confirmada"),

    "¿Reponer?": st.column_config.CheckboxColumn(
        "¿Reponer?",
        help="Selecciona si deseas reponer este producto",
    )
 }

df_respHist_nuevo = st.data_editor(
    st.session_state['df_reposicionHistorica'],
    column_config=column_config,
    hide_index=True,
    disabled=disabled_columns  # Deshabilitar las columnas especificadas

)

This is how they currently look, we would like to put a light green color on them.

I'm hoping to be able to change the color of the graphics I provided above to another color like light green or apple green.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
